Doom Neovim on Windows OS?
Does anyone know how to get a fully working Doom Neovim but on a Windows machine?
Maybe using tools like CygWIN?

Anyway, I just dig up the topic and found out that the nvim config on Windows is at
AppData\Local\nvim\

And here I can clone the doom nvim repo and it works
